# vim wrong encryption key

Tags: vim

When opening a vim encrypted file, it prompts for the password. But if I get it wrong, vim will show me garbage. How do I tell vim to reopen the file with a new password? Even if I close the buffer and open again, it won't ask the password, and I have to quit vim completely.

(Vim version 7.2 / 2008)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `:h encryption`:

> If want to start reading a file that uses a different key, set the 'key'
>   option to an empty string, so that Vim will prompt for a new one.